# After updating conda I get a CommandNotFoundError for conda

Tags: anaconda, conda, git-bash

After updating `conda` I can no longer run commands such as `conda list`, I now see the following error when I try a conda command:

```
CommandNotFoundError: No command 'conda conda'
```

The conda update was performed like so:

```
$ conda update -n base -c defaults conda
Collecting package metadata: ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\home\miniconda

  added / updated specs:
    - conda


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    conda-4.6.9                |           py37_0         1.7 MB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         1.7 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  pip                pkgs/main/win-64::pip-19.0.3-py37_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  conda                                        4.6.8-py37_0 --> 4.6.9-py37_0


Proceed ([y]/n)?


Downloading and Extracting Packages
conda-4.6.9          | 1.7 MB    | ########## | 100%
Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... done
```

My `.bashrc` file has the following line in it, and it also results in the above error upon creation of a new git/bash console on Windows 10:

```
eval "$('/c/home/miniconda/Scripts/conda.exe' 'shell.bash' 'hook')"
```

Is the above part of the problem?

My `PATH` environment variable contains conda-related paths at the front:

```
$ echo $PATH
/c/home/miniconda/condabin:/c/home/miniconda/Scripts:...

$ which conda
/c/home/miniconda/Scripts/conda

$ ll /c/home/miniconda/condabin
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 2 James Adams 197121 1995 Mar 29 21:46 _conda_activate.bat
-rw-r--r-- 2 James Adams 197121  147 Mar 29 21:46 activate.bat
-rw-r--r-- 2 James Adams 197121 1063 Mar 29 21:46 conda.bat
-rw-r--r-- 2 James Adams 197121  530 Mar 29 21:46 conda_auto_activate.bat
-rw-r--r-- 2 James Adams 197121  649 Mar 29 21:46 conda_hook.bat
-rw-r--r-- 2 James Adams 197121  192 Mar 29 21:46 deactivate.bat
-rw-r--r-- 2 James Adams 197121   65 Mar 29 21:46 rename_tmp.bat
```

Can anyone suggest how to fix this issue?

Comment: `conda conda`? That's not a valid command. Could you please change your question to show the output (error) from `conda info` instead? Also, what is the Python version in the **base** env?

Comment: Thanks, @merv. Agreed, I am only using one "conda" in my commands, but it is somehow doubled up. I can't even get the output of `conda info`, as I get the same CommandNotFoundError (No command 'conda conda'). It's as if my shell somehow has an alias such as `alias conda='conda conda'`, but I'm not seeing any such alias in place. The base env is Python version 3.7, but I can't activate it now since `conda activate myenv` will give the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: Ah okay - I was wondering if that was the case; strange! I don't know the details of a Windows config. Do you have a `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` anywhere, and if so, could you check for and post the Conda-managed section?  Also, can you run Conda using `/c/home/miniconda/bin/conda`?

Comment: Yes, I can run conda using `/c/home/miniconda/bin/conda`. The conda relevant command within `.bashrc` is listed in the question above. I can't activate using that full path to conda due to an issue where an error is reported that the shell isn't properly configured to use 'conda activate'. I have tried running `/c/home/miniconda/bin/conda init bash` (which I've done before) but that seems to have made no difference, i.e. I still see the error `CommandNotFoundError: No command 'conda conda'` when I open a new shell console window.

Comment: What is it trying to do in `init` (output from `conda init -d -vv`)? I'd probably try removing all the Conda stuff from `bashrc`, take Conda off `PATH`, etc. Then rerun `/c/home/miniconda/bin/conda init -vv` to get a fresh take. I've found `conda init` (which is technically still considered experimental) to behave strangely when there is already a managed section. Also, it'd better to edit your question, than posting all this in comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This cropped up for me today too. It appears to be a bug in conda 4.6.9.
I deleted everything conda-related but `C:\Users\[username]\Anaconda3` and `C:\Users\[username]\Anaconda3\Scripts` from my PATH and `conda` commands started working. I still couldn't run `source activate [environment]` in bash without getting:

```
CommandNotFoundError: No command 'conda conda'
```

So I downgraded to 4.6.8 with:

```
conda install conda=4.6.8
```

And it solved my problem.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! All I needed to do is run the command `/c/home/miniconda/Scripts/conda install conda=4.6.8` and then opened a new shell to be back in business.

Comment: This has been addressed in `conda 4.6.14` so also running `conda update conda -y` fixes this and moves forward. :) https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8506

Answer (score 0):

I too have been getting this error. Just like Gregory Allan stated, downgrading conda to 4.6.8 fixed it for me, and everything would work as intended.

Another way of downgrading without running a command in the terminal is to use Anaconda Navigator, and then you can select the packages you want to update or downgrade.