# Unable to downgrade conda

Tags: anaconda, conda

I have been having [issues after updating conda to 4.6.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55477806/after-updating-conda-i-get-a-commandnotfounderror-for-conda) and tried to downgrade to 4.6.8 by running

`conda install conda=4.6.8` within my preferred conda env.

When I check the version via `conda --version`, however, I notice that the version is still 4.6.9.

Is there something else I need to do to get downgrade conda?

Running this on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to downgrade conda while in `base` environment and not my preferred environment.

Comment: Conda should only ever be installed in the base environment.

Comment: I didn't think it would be possible to have an environment without conda. Why should it be only installed in base environment? How would you install packages in other environments without conda in that environment?

Comment: The conda executable in the base environment always remains on the `PATH` (or the `conda` shell function is always available, depending on the conda version). You only need one conda, and as you see here, the error was resolved by downgrading the conda in the base environment, i.e., the one that's actually being used.