# Why do I get different results while activating anaconda environment in different terminals on Windows?

Tags: windows, terminal, anaconda, conda, environment

I'm trying to activate anaconda environment using command window. When I open cmd and run `activate testenv` everything is ok.

But when I use git for windows, neither `activate testenv` nor `conda activate testenv` works.

It raises error: `CommandNotFoundError: No command 'conda conda'.`

Comment: Looks like Git for Windows doesn't take account of the Windows `PATH` then.

Comment: @nekomatic thank you. But how can I check that? If I try some test commands in git, responses seem to be normal. Here are some examples:  

  
    $ conda --version  
    conda 4.6.11  

    $ conda list  
    WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in     a future release.  
    + list of packages   

    $ jupyter lab  
    -> runs jupyter lab

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After updating conda I get a CommandNotFoundError for conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55477806/after-updating-conda-i-get-a-commandnotfounderror-for-conda). There is also [an issue on the repo for this](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8506).

Comment: @merv thanks! Downgrading to 4.6.8 solved the issue